# left-right join

Tags: mysql

Сделал тройной left/right join, чтобы вывести в трех колонках результаты трех запросов.

```
SELECT t1.order_number as order_t1, t2.order_number as order_t2, t3.order_number as order_t3 FROM
        (       SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')

        ) as t1
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
                AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')
        ) as t2
        ON t1.order_id  = t2.order_id
LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')
        ) as t3
        ON t2.order_id  = t3.order_id
    UNION ALL
        SELECT t1.order_number as order_t1, t2.order_number as order_t2, t3.order_number as order_t3 FROM
        (       SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')

        ) as t1
        RIGHT JOIN
        (SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
                AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')
        ) as t2
        ON t1.order_id  = t2.order_id
RIGHT JOIN
        (SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                                FROM `order`
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')
        ) as t3
       ON t2.order_id  = t3.order_id
```

Выводит данные в первой и третьей колонках корректно, во второй одни null. Если не джойнить третий запрос, то выводит результаты первой и второй колонок правильно. Почему может не выводить результат второй колонки? И возможно ли удалить null-значения из всех колонок?
UPD. Если сделать только для двух запросов, то выводит данные в обоих колонках

```
SELECT t1.order_number as order_t1, t2.order_number as order_t2 FROM
        (       SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')

        ) as t1
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
                AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')
        ) as t2
        ON t1.order_id  = t2.order_id
    UNION ALL
        SELECT t1.order_number as order_t1, t2.order_number as order_t2 FROM
        (       SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')

        ) as t1
        RIGHT JOIN
        (SELECT order_number,`order`.order_id 
                FROM `order` 
                inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
                where order_status = 'delivered' AND order_statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
                AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7  DAY)
                and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')
        ) as t2
        ON t1.order_id  = t2.order_id
```

Comment: Если я верно понимаю логику, то Вы собираете данные по принципу "берём за последнюю неделю, и добавляем данные за последние 10 дней без этой недели и за последние 2 месяца без этих 10 дней", верно? Если так - то у Вас косая логика, и третий подзапрос следует связывать с первым, а не со вторым.

Comment: Логика следующая, первый запрос - данные за 7 дней, второй - 8-10дней, третий - 11 дней и более. если вы имели ввиду это `ON t1.order_id  = t3.order_id`, то пробовал, все равно вторая колонка пустая.

Comment: Лучше бы описали какие данные у вас в таблицах и какой результат хотите получить. Ваши подзапросы по одному order_id сейчас гарантированно дают 0 или 1 запись ? Если они вдруг могут дать более одной записи - то на выходе вообще ахинея из перемноженных данных будет. Судя по всему вы пытаетесь эмулировать full outer join, но его лучше эмулировать совсем другими методами - union, group by и разворачивание в горизонталь, а раз так то скорее всего вашу задачу можно решить за одно обращение к таблице

Comment: `Логика следующая` - ну я сказал то же, другими словами просто.

Comment: Если `from t1 left join t2 on t1.f1=t2.f1` даёт записи для t2, а `from t1 left join t2 on t1.f1=t2.f1 left join t3 on tX.f1=t3.f1` для t2 их не даёт, то между запросами в части t1-t2 есть разница.

Comment: @Mike в таблице уникальные номера. Соответственно, один номер может быть только в одном таймфрейме.

Comment: @cruim т.е. по факту вы хотите получить табличку в которой для одного order_number будет одна запись в которой в двух колонках будет NULL, а в одной написан номер этого заказа. так ?

Comment: @Mike хочу получить таблицу, в колонках которых будут номера заказов, соответствующих определенному таймфрейму.

Comment: @Akina добавил апдейт в вопрос, где только два джойна и данные второй колонки выводятся.

Comment: Попробуйте проалиасить одинаковые имена таблиц в разных джойнах

Comment: @cruim Это я понял. order_number может быть одновременно только в одной колонке ?

Comment: @Mike да, один номер,может находится только в одной колонке.

Comment: Согласен с **Alex Shmalex** - попробуйте в каждом подзапросе таблицам `order` и `order_delivery_data` дать уникальные в пределах всего запроса алиасы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю нужные данные вы получите примерно таким запросом:

```
SELECT IF(diff<7,order_number,NULL) order_t1,
       IF(diff>=7 and diff<=10,order_number,NULL) order_t2,
       IF(diff>10,order_number,NULL) order_t3
  FROM (
    SELECT `order`.order_id,order_number,datediff(CURRENT_DATE, order_statusUpdatedAt) diff
      FROM `order` 
     inner join order_delivery_data on `order`.order_id = order_delivery_data.order_id
     where order_status = 'delivered'
       AND order_statusUpdatedAt >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 60 DAY)
       and order_delivery_data_name in ('Казахстан Курьеры')
  ) X
```

Comment: и всего 11 строк...спасибо!